# Installing helm chart inside a Go k8s custom controller for CRD: pros and cons?

Tags: kubernetes, helm, kubernetes-helm, go

I am writing a k8s operator using kubebuilder and Go. I have a few CRDs and controllers. One of the controllers needs to create a collection of statefulsets, deployments, services, etc. when a custom object is created.

I see the following options to achieve that:

1. Use Go structs to define all the k8s objects. This option is flexible, but it means that I need to get some people to start writing Go code instead of putting together simple yaml files like they are used to in helm.
2. Make a helm install inside the Reconcile() function. This is easy for a simple fire and forget happy path. However it seems hacky and I am not sure what kind of issues I can face down the road and where I can potentially find myself stuck and/or extremely limited.

I don't think OperatorSDK Helm based operators are a good option for me, because some other controllers I have need to perform actions like calling other services, do some validation, etc.

Can someone help me understand the pros and cons of each approach?